# How can I enable mod_wsgi in Apache2.4.57.0 on Windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

Apache/2.4.57 (Win64)
Django 2.4.2
I am new to Django and I tried to connect it with Apache through mod_wsgi but it seems new versions of Apache does not support such kind of module. I installed mod_wsgi wheel in Anaconda with pip. Am I right? Or is there any different way I could deploy my Django project in production? I saw on the official page I could use nginx. Any opinions?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? We do not do software recommendations here, and [all the options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/) are good and bad for their own reasons.